# how to display search result in Angular

Tags: html, angular, search, filter, angular-material

I'm doing Mat-Chips Angular project and I'm wondering how I can display the result of the user input.

So right now I have a user input and a data inside the TS file.

Under the search box, I want to display the result in number on how many item are matched when a user find something and if there is nothing that matched then display "We found {#} item when we search for {what ever current user text is }".

Just to clarify,

```
User input "Adam" and find 3 chips
Display => We found "3" item when we search for "Adam"

User input "Jack"
Display => We found "0" item when we search for "Jack"
```

Here is my stackblitz project 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflowcom-a-60857864-6433166-lfrxc4

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Stackblitz -  https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflowcom-a-60857864-6433166-nxabae

````
<div [ngClass]="[users.length ? 'w-20' : 'w-50']">
        <p style="margin-top: 25px;">

            <input [formControl]="inputCtrl" matInput class="input" >
      <br>
        <mat-hint *ngIf="_filteredTags.length >0;else noResults">
          <p *ngIf="inputCtrl.value"> We found ({{_filteredTags?.length}}) item when we search for "{{inputCtrl.value}}"</p>
        </mat-hint>

        </p>
            <div class="tag-header">Tags</div>
            <div style="margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 25px;">
                <div>
                    <mc-tags (tagFilterValue)="_filterTags($value)" [chips]="_filteredTags"></mc-tags>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
      <ng-template #noResults>
        <div>We found ({{_filteredTags?.length}}) item when we search for "{{inputCtrl.value}}"  </div>
      </ng-template>
    ```
````